# kube-up.sh failes in OpenStack

Tags: kubernetes, openstack, openstack-heat

I'm trying to install Kubernetes in an internal OpenStack environment using Heat. I'm following the instructions give here -> http://kubernetes.io/docs/getting-started-guides/openstack-heat/

While issuing the command `./cluster/kube-up.sh/`, I hit the following issue:

```
... Starting cluster using provider: openstack-heat
... calling verify-prereqs
swift client installed
glance client installed
nova client installed
heat client installed
[INFO] Uploading kubernetes-server-linux-amd64.tar.gz
kubernetes-server.tar.gz
[INFO] Uploading kubernetes-salt.tar.gz
kubernetes-salt.tar.gz
[INFO] Key pair already exists
Stack not found: KubernetesStack
[INFO] Create stack KubernetesStack
Image ID: 44284b7f-4f83-4c5d-89a2-992fab6ddaa3
Master flavor: m1.small
ERROR: Property error: : resources.kube_master.properties.image: : No module named v1.client
```

My environment variables are as follows:

```
export OS_TENANT_NAME=Kubernetes
export OS_USERNAME=admin
export OS_PASSWORD=xxxxx
export OS_AUTH_URL=http://localhost:5000/v2.0
export OS_TENANT_ID=c240c1db536847db94a82a3e1547ab91
export OS_REGION_NAME=RegionOne
export STACK_NAME=KubernetesStack
export NUMBER_OF_MINIONS=2
export MAX_NUMBER_OF_MINIONS=2
export MASTER_FLAVOR=m1.small
export MINION_FLAVOR=m1.small
export EXTERNAL_NETWORK=ext-net
export DNS_SERVER=139.25.25.243
export IMAGE_URL_PATH=http://cloud.centos.org/centos/7/images
export IMAGE_FILE=CentOS-7-x86_64-GenericCloud-1510.qcow2
export SWIFT_SERVER_URL=http://10.10.0.10:8888/v1/AUTH_c240c1db536847db94a82a3e1547ab91
export ENABLE_PROXY=true
export HTTP_PROXY=http://10.10.0.1:3128
export HTTPS_PROXY=http://10.10.0.1:3128
export NO_PROXY=10.10.0.10,localhost
export CLIENT_PUBLIC_KEY_PATH=/home/controller/k8s/kubernetes/ssh/id_rsa.pub
export FIXED_NETWORK_CIDR=192.168.0.0/24
export CREATE_IMAGE=false
export DOWNLOAD_IMAGE=false
export IMAGE_ID=44284b7f-4f83-4c5d-89a2-992fab6ddaa3
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you try with **DOWNLOAD_IMAGE=true** and see what happens?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone's interested, I manage to fix this issue.

The problem was my python-cinderclient and python-glanceclient were not compatible with my heat engine, which was of liberty. I downgraded the CLI packages to a liberty compatible version and it worked.